# Custom fonts not working in tailwindcss v3.1.6

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

I want to use custom fonts in my app but the custom fonts wont work.

tailwind.config.cjs:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        heliosbold: ["HeliosBold", "sans-serif"],
        helios: ["Helios", "sans-serif"],
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

global.css:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: HeliosBold;
    src: url('/fonts/heliosBold.woff2') format('woff2');
    font-weight: 400;
    font-display: swap;
    font-style: normal;
  }
  
  
  @font-face {
    font-family: Helios;
    src: url('/fonts/helios.woff2') format('woff2');
    font-weight: 400;
    font-display: swap;
    font-style: normal;
  }

@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

I used this exact code and it worked fine in tailwind 3.0.24, but it doesn't work in 3.1.6 anyone knows what has changed/what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: When you say it isn't working, can you clarify what the issue is. Can you see `.font-helios` being generated in the css output? Or is it an issue with the css output being ok but the fonts aren't loading?

Comment: @stickyuser yes the font does get generated in the css output, but the font-face doesnt get used

Comment: Can you see the font files loading in the network tab of your browser dev tools?